# CSS: Adding position fixed makes header go to the right?

Tags: css

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/potcD

In the header css, why is it that when I add position: fixed the symposiums text goes all the way to the left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you are giving position fixed the header takes the width of the content, so specify the width.

Try this style

```
header{
  position:fixed;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  width:100%;
  left:0;
  text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: I'm not fixed on what I want yet. I'm just confused why in my original  code "symposiums" is slightly to the left of center, and when I add position:fixed to header it turns to the left

Comment: @user3469931 check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/39james/udu3p/1/, i added the styles i mentioned above and it looks fine. Can you check this fiddle and let me know if it is still not working for you.

Comment: Yes your code works fine, but that's not my question. My code works fine too when I add position fixed. I'm confused specifically as to why the position of the header changes with and without position fixed. I would like to run a javascript that adds position fixed to header after a certain amount of scroll, and for consistency it should look the same

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/potcD vs http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zGofi/ , why is one to the slightly left while the other is all the way to the left when the only difference is position: fixed? <--That's my question

Comment: First of all you are giving margin and padding in %. Open both the above codepens in two tabs, make the margin and padding 0. Then you can see the static header width is the width of its parent div content, whereas the fixed header width is just the width of the header content. So when you apply margin and padding in %, these values will be calculated based on the width and height of the corresponding content. Now try adding 1% padding-right to header in both codpens and you can see the displacement of the content, by how much the content moves with 1%. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Ah okay thanks, so basically when position fixed is added the element is taken out of its parent container?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do.

I've played with it a bit... Please check out my [CodePen fork](http://codepen.io/ryanw/pen/Esljw) of your work.

HTML

```
<header><div class="logo">symposiums</div></header>
<div class="content">
  <p>
1.a convivial meeting, usually following a dinner, for drinking and intellectual conversation.<br>
2.( initial capital letter, italics ) a philosophical dialogue (4th century b.c.) by Plato, dealing with ideal love and the vision of absolute beauty.</p>
<p>i realize that i have to live, to experience life and to do new things everyday. That is the antidote for boredom, procrastination and sulking. Don't let things be a routine, or else time will just fly by. Twas a good night.</p><br>
<p>And we gotta be a superhero, a renaissance man, against this all. everyones need an outlet for expression,  a skill in the arts, music, dance, writing, etc.</p>
and i need to put my feet on the ground, remember i am not special, pay my dues, and still put my mind in the skies.
<br><br><br><br><p><center>The mind is it's own place, and in itself can make a heaven of hell or a hell of heaven. John Milton.</p>

<h2>I WONDER</h2></center>

  <p>I'm too emasculated for this shit
  <br>jobs, aren't they buying part of your life? and i want family and freedom<br>
  <font color="red"> but of course you won't feel anything, not accomplishment nor desire, if you don't put seriousness and passion into</font></p>

  <p>Twenty years from now you will be more disappointed by the things that you didn't do than by the ones you did do. So throw off the bowlines.  Sail away from the safe harbor.  Catch the trade winds in your sails.  Explore.  Dream.  Discover.</p>

  <p>the thing is it doesn't matter how much you read. there is a certain extent, you have to do, to experience, and nothing can replace that. what do i do?</p>

</div>
```

CSS

```
header
    {
      margin: 0;
  position:fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;

    background: #BDBDBD;
    font-size: 250%; 
    line-height: 200%; 
    opacity: 0.5;
height: 72px;
    }

header .logo {
  width: 35%;
  left: 22%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
    font-family: georgia;
    font-variant: small-caps;
}

header .logo:first-letter
    {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: red;
    font-family: times;
    }

body 

    {
    cursor: crosshair; 
    font-family: helvetica; 
    font-size: 90%; 
    opacity: .7;
    }


h2 

    {
    font-family: arial, helvetica; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    font-size: 550%; 
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px grey;
    }



.content

    {
margin: 80px auto;
    text-align: left;
    width: 35%;
    border: 2px dotted grey;
    padding: 0 4% 15% 4%;
    }
```

Comment: I'm not fixed on what I want yet. I'm just confused why in my original code "symposiums" is slightly to the left of center, and when I add position:fixed to header it turns to the left

Comment: Where do you want it to be? It is in a strange position because of your excessive margins and padding.